# android in-app billing, Dungeons example. Where the SQLite .db files are stored?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I just installed Dungeons sample code in my phone. I am using adb tool for viewing messages in my computer via "usb debugging" but I also want to see the contents of the SQLite tables.

I cannot see in the doumentation how I can access these tables? Maybe they are in the directory that the app wan installed? But what is this default directory?

I found that I can use sqlite3 tool from adb (http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#sqlite) but I cannot find the corresponding DB inside the android.

Plz help, thank you

Answer (score 1):

sqlite database are stored on a per application basis. They're ususally stored in `/data/data/your.package.name/databases`.

Comment: yes but I cannot have access to this database. it refuses to change to that directory. Is there a way to run sqlite3 and make queries for example?

Comment: Why can't you access that directory?